# SQL Query: How to send MIN value from one table to another based off ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Looking for help with SQL query!

I have 2 tables, A and B. Both tables have the column 'student_id' and 'created_date'. For table A, 'created_date' is null but I wish to populate it with data from table B.

In table B, there are multiple of the same 'student_id' values, so I am trying to fetch only the one that has the earliest 'created_date'.

Once I get that date, I want to then go back to table A, look for that exact same 'student_id' and then insert that MIN 'created_date' into table A.

If anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated!

```
UPDATE student as A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(student_registration.created_date) mindate, student_id FROM student_registration GROUP By student_id ) B 
ON A.student_id = B.student_id 
SET A.`created_date` = B.mindate 
WHERE A.`created_date` is null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like this

```
Update Tablea A 
inner join (SELECT MIN(`created_date`) mindate, student_id 
FROM Tableb 
GROUP By student_id ) B 
On A.student_id = B.student_id 
Set A.`created_date` = B.mindate 
Where A.`created_date` is NULL ;
```

With the inner join you find the minimal Date in TableB and it is the right one for the student_id.

The rest is simple Updatelogic.

With the Where Clause at the end you can select only the rows that you need.

For **Postgresql** is the query like this

```
UPDATE student as A 
SET created_date = B.mindate 
FROM (Select MIN(created_date) as mindate, student_id 
From student_registration 
  GROUP BY student_id)
as B
WHERE A.student_id = B.student_id 
AND A.created_date is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have been trying to figure out the issue, but I am getting syntax error at "inner join". Any idea why?

Comment: post your query in your post

Comment: Updated. I am using PostgreSQL is that makes any difference. Thank you.

Comment: @Sunny Yes it makes a huge difference, thats why we have different tags. I edited my post so that you have also a postgresql exqample.

Comment: Apologies for forgetting it! The second query worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help!